# How do I find duplicate entries in a database table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query will display all Dewey Decimal numbers that have been duplicated in the "book" table:

```
SELECT dewey_number, 
 COUNT(dewey_number) AS NumOccurrences
FROM book
GROUP BY dewey_number
HAVING ( COUNT(dewey_number) > 1 )
```

However, what I'd like to do is have my query display the name of the authors associated with the duplicated entry (the "book" table and "author" table are connected by "author_id").  In other words, the query above would yield the following:

```
dewey_number | NumOccurrences
------------------------------
5000         | 2
9090         | 3
```

What I'd like the results to display is something similar to the following:

```
author_last_name | dewey_number | NumOccurrences
-------------------------------------------------
Smith            | 5000         | 2
Jones            | 5000         | 2
Jackson          | 9090         | 3
Johnson          | 9090         | 3
Jeffers          | 9090         | 3
```

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.  And, in case it comes into play, I'm using a Postgresql DB.

**UPDATE**: Please note that "author_last_name" is not in the "book" table.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows Can someone close please?

Comment: Read it more closely.  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. He wants to *find* the duplicate rows (and more that that), not to remove them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A nested query can do the job.

```
SELECT author_last_name, dewey_number, NumOccurrences
FROM author INNER JOIN
     ( SELECT author_id, dewey_number,  COUNT(dewey_number) AS NumOccurrences
        FROM book
        GROUP BY author_id, dewey_number
        HAVING ( COUNT(dewey_number) > 1 ) ) AS duplicates
ON author.id = duplicates.author_id
```

(I don't know if this is the fastest way to achieve what you want.)

Update: Here is my data

```
SELECT * FROM author;
 id | author_last_name 
----+------------------
  1 | Fowler
  2 | Knuth
  3 | Lang

SELECT * FROM book;
 id | author_id | dewey_number |         title          
----+-----------+--------------+------------------------
  1 |         1 |          600 | Refactoring
  2 |         1 |          600 | Refactoring
  3 |         1 |          600 | Analysis Patterns
  4 |         2 |          600 | TAOCP vol. 1
  5 |         2 |          600 | TAOCP vol. 1
  6 |         2 |          600 | TAOCP vol. 2
  7 |         3 |          500 | Algebra
  8 |         3 |          500 | Undergraduate Analysis
  9 |         1 |          600 | Refactoring
 10 |         2 |          500 | Concrete Mathematics
 11 |         2 |          500 | Concrete Mathematics
 12 |         2 |          500 | Concrete Mathematics
```

And here is the result of the above query:

```
 author_last_name | dewey_number | numoccurrences 
------------------+--------------+----------------
 Fowler           |          600 |              4
 Knuth            |          600 |              3
 Knuth            |          500 |              3
 Lang             |          500 |              2
```

Comment: Ok, probably a nested query is overkill, but now I'm sure it works. Tony Andrews' comment on the author_id column applies here too.

Comment: By the way, why are you searching for duplicates based on author's name and Dewey code? Duplicates (multiple copies of the same book, I guess) should be based also on the book's title...

Comment: I updated the code, but it returns 0 results. As for the use case question, I simply created a dummy scenario -- I'm not actually working on detecting duplicate books.

Comment: "I updated the code, but it returns 0 results." I executed this code in psql with two tables like yours and it returned the expected data. Check your data. Let me work out the details, then I'll update my post.

Comment: OK, I found part of the problem on my end -- a couple fields were missing DD numbers. Unfortunately, the query doesn't yield the desired result -- it only displays the name of a single author with books that have duplicated DD numbers.

Comment: Update your data so author_id=1 only has one "600" and author_id=2 only has one 600.  Do you still get a result back for "600"?

Comment: Of course not. And there should not be any, otherwise your question is wrong. You can't expect a query to choose arbitrarily an author_id from those (many) having an entry with dewey=600  and have that author_id joined with table author.

Answer (score 20):

You probably want this

```
SELECT dewey_number, author_last_name,
 COUNT(dewey_number) AS NumOccurrences
FROM book
GROUP BY dewey_number,author_last_name
HAVING ( COUNT(dewey_number) > 1 )
```

Comment: "author_last_name" is not in the "book" table.  The "book" table and "author" table are connected by a FKed "author_id" in the "book" table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT dewey_number, author_last_name,
       COUNT(dewey_number) AS NumOccurrences
FROM book
JOIN author USING (author_id)
GROUP BY dewey_number,author_last_name
HAVING COUNT(dewey_number) > 1
```

If book.author_id can be null then change the join to:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN author USING (author_id)
```

If the author_id column has a different name in each table then you can't use USING, use ON instead:

```
JOIN author ON author.id = book.author_id
```

or

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN author ON author.id = book.author_id
```

Comment: No luck on this one.  It returns 0 results.

Comment: Do both tables have a column AUTHOR_ID as you stated?  My USING syntax assumes that.  If not change to "JOIN author ON author.xxx = book.yyy".  If the query returns 0 rows (without error) that suggests that there the authors table is empty?

Comment: I think we're getting closer.  I did neglect to mention that it's "author.id" and "book.author_id", so good call on USING vs ON.  I updated accordingly, but Postgresql didn't like the bracketed "[LEFT JOIN]".  After removing the brackets, it yields 0 results.

Comment: And, no, neither "id" field can be null.

Comment: Sorry, the brackets around LEFT OUTER were my way of saying that these keywords were optional

Answer (score 0):

```
select author_name,dewey_number,Num_of_occur
from author a,(select author_id,dewey_number,count(dewey_number) Num_of_occur
                from   book
                group by author_id,dewey_number
                having count(dewey_number) > 1) dup
where a.author_id = dup.author_id
```

Comment: In addition to providing code, can you also explain why this answer will work?

Comment: You will get an error because author_last_name is not in the group by or in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple and efective way i found is show below:

```
SELECT
    p.id
    , p.full_name
    , (SELECT count(id) FROM tbl_documents as t where t.person_id = p.id) as rows
FROM tbl_people as p
WHERE 
    p.id 
IN (SELECT d.person_id FROM tbl_documents as d 
    GROUP BY d.person_id HAVING count(d.id) > 1) 
ORDER BY 
    p.full_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from author
dewey_number    author_last_name
1   Ramu
2   Rajes
1   Samy
1   Ramu

select * from book
authorid    dewey_number
1   1
2   1

select a.dewey_number,a.author_last_name,count(a.dewey_number) from author a
where a.dewey_number in (
select b.dewey_number from book b )
group by a.dewey_number,a.author_last_name

dewey_number    author_last_name    (No column name)
1   Ramu    2
1   Samy    1
```