# Postgresql: Flagging and Identifying Duplicates

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I'm trying to find a way to mark duplicated cases similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435964/how-do-i-find-duplicate-entries-in-a-database-table).

However, instead of counting occurrences of duplicated values, I'd like to mark them as `0` and `1`, for duplicated and unique cases respectively. This is very similar to `SPSS`'s identify duplicate cases function. For example if I have a dataset like:

```
Name    State    Gender
John     TX        M
Katniss  DC        F
Noah     CA        M
Katniss  CA        F
John     SD        M
Ariel    FL        F
```

And if I wanted to flag those with duplicated name, so the output would be something like this:

```
Name    State    Gender   Dup
John     TX        M       1
Katniss  DC        F       1 
Noah     CA        M       1
Katniss  CA        F       0
John     SD        M       0
Ariel    FL        F       1
```

A bonus would be a query statement that will handle which case to pick when determining the unique case.

Comment: 1) Does your table have a primary key (such as an id) ? 2) WHY is {John,TX} a dup, and {John,SD} not? 3) Why is {Ariel,FL} a dup ? 4) same for {Noah,CA}

Comment: For this example, we can assume that the names are primary keys. I may have phrased it wrong but Ariel and Noah are not duplicates. It's the first occurrence of Ariel and Noah so it's flagged as a 1. While the 2nd Katniss and John are zero because there was a Katniss and John before (row 1 and 2).

Comment: You had the sign inverted. (that's why I named my result column `nodup`)

Comment: I'm confused as to what is inverted (so I can fix it). The idea is to get a 1 for unique cases and 0 for duplicated cases. Does this help?

Comment: That is fine, but please don't name the variable `Dup`, then. Name it `NoDup` or `Wanted`, or whatever describes its purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, state, gender
    , NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM names nx
            WHERE nx.name = na.name
              AND nx.gender = na.gender
              AND nx.ctid < na.ctid) AS Is_not_a_dup
FROM names na
   ;
```

---

Explanation: `[NOT] EXISTS(...)` results in a boolean value (which could be converted to an integer) Casting to boolean requires an extra pair of `()` , though:

```
SELECT name, state, gender
        , (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM names nx
                WHERE nx.name = na.name
                  AND nx.gender = na.gender
                  AND nx.ctid < na.ctid))::integer AS is_not_a_dup
FROM names na
       ;
```

---

Results:

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
  name   | state | gender | nodup 
---------+-------+--------+-------
 John    | TX    | M      | t
 Katniss | DC    | F      | t
 Noah    | CA    | M      | t
 Katniss | CA    | F      | f
 John    | SD    | M      | f
 Ariel   | FL    | F      | t
(6 rows)

  name   | state | gender | nodup 
---------+-------+--------+-------
 John    | TX    | M      |     1
 Katniss | DC    | F      |     1
 Noah    | CA    | M      |     1
 Katniss | CA    | F      |     0
 John    | SD    | M      |     0
 Ariel   | FL    | F      |     1
(6 rows)
```

Comment: I have no doubt you're correct but I'm having a bit of trouble interpreting this (I'm still new to postgres). Are `nx` and `na` different tables within a database? Also where does the `ctid` come from?

Comment: No, it is the *same* table. You should read the subquery as "does there exist another record with the same name, but with a different recordnumber?"  That subquery yields a boolean value for every record of the main query. ctid is a "hidden columns", a *kind* of rownumber, guaranteed to be different for every row. I needed it because there was no PK/id column available for that purpuse.

Comment: No, it is a *hidden* column, maintained by the DBMS for its own purposes (row versioning). Other DBMSses may have other usable columns (tid,tidp,rownum,...) that could be used. BTW: you can avoid the need for ctid (and the confusion) by having a PRIMARY KEY (or UNIQUE constraint) for every table.